# Deploying Rails 4.1 to AWS failed to precompile assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I know this sounds noob, but I can't get a clue on what is wrong.

I've created a EB instance with passenger, following a tutorial, the last step is to run

```
    $ eb deploy
```

Which gives me

```
    INFO: Environment update is starting.
    INFO: Deploying new version to instance(s).
    ERROR: [Instance: i-71f70593] Command failed on instance. Return code: 137 Output: (TRUNCATED)... /var/app/ondeck/public/assets/priorizations/simplified/upper-5154a5b0c3e6cbf5463df08c05ab0bb4.png
    I, [2015-09-21T23:00:17.233813 #26607]  INFO -- : Writing /var/app/ondeck/public/assets/application-ea5935c63d274c4625db69541c62d788.js
    Killed (core dumped).
    Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/11_asset_compilation.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
    INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
    ERROR: Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) '*****'. Aborting the operation.
    ERROR: Failed to deploy application.
```

The /var/log/eb-activity.log file has nothing interesting (I think)

Can someone help me, please?

Obs: The project is fine locally and on heroku.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Were you able to determine what the problem was?

Comment: Same issue here, but intermittent.

Answer (score 2):

I also was having the same exact error (`Killed (core dumped)`) during asset precompilation. Was not intermittent for me - I would consistenly get it every time.

Increasing the EC2 instance size fixed the issue for me. I suspect memory was the lacking resource - CPU at 100% during precompilation has never been a problem for me.